# Defining Text Box templates in Powerpoint (2016)

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have text of several types (e.g. citations, image captions, etc) that I need to insert into my slides. I would like to create a template text box for each, so that I don't have to apply the different sets of formatting to each type of text. However, I see that one can only define a default text box, rather than several types/styles of text box. Is there a workaround for this? I could of course use titles and subtitles as elements in the standard Layout of a slide, and customise them from the Master View, but I would like to have more liberty than that, i.e. to create several types of text box, each from its own separate template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't directly possible in PowerPoint.

There are a couple of rather clumsy partial solutions involving copy/pasting formatting (but not size/placement) or setting the default then adding e.g. all your captions, changing the default, adding your citations and so on.

I have a commercial PowerPoint add-in that allows you to create styles in PowerPoint (for shapes as well as text). There's a free demo that limits you to five styles; if that's enough to meet your needs, there'd be no cost.  It doesn't time out or anything like that.

If interested, visit http://www.pptools.com/shapestyles/

Comment: thanks Steve, I installed the add-in, but couldn't find the Pick Up Style button as instructed in the Help!

Comment: On the Add-ins tab, you should see a sort of toolbar with an eye-dropper icon, a dropdown list box, another eyedropper icon and a ? help icon.  The leftmost button, the eyedropper with an arrow that points up and to the right, is the pick up style button.